# Difference between this two java codes in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I founded two types of jsp codes but both are for same purpose.

1 type of code as shown

```
  <%!
  String firstname;
  String lastname;

  %>
```

and 2 type of code is as shown

```
    <%!
       public class Employee {
               protected String firstName;
               protected String lastName;

          public String getFirstName () {
                  return (firstName);
              }
           public String getLastName (){
                    return (lastName);
              }      
       }
   %>
```

Is their any application security difference between this two type declarations.
Tell to me about what is the difference between these two type of declarations.

Comment: They both are bad approach. Second one is worse that first one. Avoid Java code in your JSPs . What you mean by  'security difference'.. ? What type of security?  A JSP in the end is a servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2nd code is example of data encapsulation in java,It is called encapsulation because

here it is accessing protected fields through public methods.

Answer (score 1):

The first declares two simple variables, while the second declares a Java inner class in JSP code.

You may not know it, but JSP are always transpiled into pure Java files before being compiled.

Now, if your question is specifically a security one, there is no difference between declaring those in JSP and in pure Java classes : you end up with two variables on one side, and one inner class with two fields on the other side.